# Connecting to the internet and installing MATE via terminal

Tags: wireless, command-line, mate

So, I installed Ubuntu 14.04 today, and everytime I log in in the GUI (Unity), my PC crashes. This also happened when I tried Ubuntu 13.10 last year, so I figured, it must be my graphics card. I have a GeForce 6150 SE nForce 430. Strangely this never happened with Ubuntu 11.04 WUBI. I am almost sure my GPU is the problem, so I want to try the MATE desktop.

Now, I know how to boot into the command line interface, so that isn't a problem. However, I can't seem to connect to the internet. I enter the `iwconfig wlan0 essid "My router"  key"My wep password"`. This seems to go okay. And when I insert `dhclient wlan0` The screen goes to the next line, but I can't enter any commands, it just stays blank forever.
You know how it always says `"pcname"@ubuntu:~#` but when I entered the dhclient, that goes away. (I know I'm explaining very basic here, but you get the point)

So I wondered if anyone could tell me which commands to enter, step by step about how to connect to wifi (Wep or wpa, doesn't matter I have 2 routers. LAN is also fine) and then install MATE desktop? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you just installed it today why not just install MATE Ubuntu from scratch? [Ubuntu MATE Remix](http://ubuntu-mate.org/)

Other non-Unity options: [LXDE](http://lubuntu.net/), [XFCE](http://xubuntu.org/), [Gnome](http://ubuntugnome.org/), or [Cinnamon](http://www.cubuntu.fr/?q=node/27)

Comment: I already saw this, and this will be my last option, but my internet is very slow because people are working in our street. Downloading a 1Gb file would take ages, but I had the Ubuntu image lying around. I only want to download MATE to minimalise download time

Answer (score 0):

I have the EXACT same video card as you. I use a custom (built by myself) LXDE version based on Ubuntu 14.04. It works perfectly on this video card using the default nouveau driver. I've went one step further and I've installed the proprietary nvidia driver version 304.117 (proprietary, tested). Everything works fine. The catch is that LXDE doesn't use any fancy 3D stuff while Unity does and it seems (from your problem description) that Unity + nouveau on GeForce 6150 SE nForce 430 not = love.

How the above could help you? You could try this:

1. Test run Lubuntu 14.04 LiveCD (Official LXDE Ubuntu) on your machine;
2. If 1. is ok then install Lubuntu 14.04;
3. Once Lubuntu 14.04 is installed and works ok, install proprietary nvidia driver - I recommend to use Additional Drivers and install the same 304.117 (proprietary, tested);
4. Reboot and see if Lubuntu 14.04 + nvidia 304.117 (proprietary, tested) is ok;
5. If 4. is ok, finally install the ubuntu-desktop metapackage to get the official Unity Ubuntu installed;
6. Logout and re-login - don't forget to select Ubuntu session on login manager screen;
7. See if Unity works now - it will be Unity + nvidia driver (not Unity + nouveau driver as you have it now). In case it doesn't works, you still have Lubuntu working that will allow you to try and change stuff via a graphical environment.

I hope this helps. Please let us know if it does!

Comment: Thanks! I love the unity look, however I was planning on trying MATE anyway, so I wasn't too upset about it, but still. Now I know how it might work with unity I'm definitely going to try it! What's the command to install it?

Comment: Well, commands I mean.

Comment: Fastest way I know to install a package is from a terminal emulator. In our case, in a terminal, run "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop" - but I guess you figured that out already. So, you've got Unity up & running on the GeForce 6150 SE nForce 430 using the nvidia driver, I understand. Glad to help!